# Add string parameter to function in onClick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

I have an onclick function with a parameter. This parameter I would like to show in a alert for example. How can I give a parameter? Something like this:

```
<img id="imgPerson" src="_#=itemImg=#_" width="200" height="200" onclick="SetDetailInfo('test value 123')"/>

function SetDetailInfo(myCustomParam) {
    alert(myCustomParam);
}
```

UPDATE
The code above is working fine. But ofcorse I dont want to give the function a fixed parameter. I would like to make it dynamic. This code below works. You see some variabe with the name "*#= line2 =#*" is printed in a div. This works and shows some string runtime. And I would like to add that value of that variable to the function as a parameter.

```
<img id="imgBestuurderFoto" src="_#=itemDate=#_" width="200" height="200" onclick="SetDetailInfo('test 123')" style="padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;" />

       <div class="cbs-Line2" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line2.defaultValueRenderer(line2)) =#_" id="_#= line2Id =#_" style="display:block;" >_#= line2 =#_</div>
```

This is the javascript with the variables:

```
var encodedId = $htmlEncode(ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId() + "_2lines_");
var line2 = $getItemValue(ctx, "IntroText");
line2.overrideValueRenderer($contentLineText);
var line2Id = encodedId + "line2";
```

Comment: That should work, have you tried it? [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JAVdW/)

Comment: Make sure you link the JS before the html.

Comment: @GaurangTandon, this isn't necessary nor a standard. In fact quite often you may want to delay loading JS until rest of the page is loaded (deferring) so that page render is not delayed.

Comment: @BartPlatak Oh I am sorry. I was confused for a moment between JSFiddle's load of the JS code, and the `script` tags. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: you are al right. This works. See update for the exactly problem..

Comment: Do not use IDs like that, instead have a backing model of your application using JavaScript object, bind the objects to the presentation. I strongly suggest you look up some patterns about how UI should be structured - for example: observer, mediator, command and strategy or architectural patterns like MVC, MVVM or MVP and get more ideas on how to structure your UI. You're solving a problem that should not exist in the first place here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm particularly a big fan of using [data-attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to the dom in elements to distribute information, try this :

```
<img id="imgPerson" src="_#=itemImg=#_" 
     width="200" height="200" data-test-attr="test value 123"/>
```

In js

```
$("#imgPerson").click(function(e){
     alert($(this).data("test-attr"));
});
```

Comment: Using data attributes in DOM elements to distribute information that is not directly related to presentation is a violation of the separation of concerns principle and usually a recipe for a disaster with spaghetti all over. Generally, clicking an element should send a command to the object that is backing that element depending on context.  Generally, your code should have a single source of truth and that should not be the presentation layer. Querying the presentation later for logical information and application state becomes a maintenance nightmare fast, especially as the code base grows.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks for the advice, I'll consider in the future. I usually use data-attributes to distribute information such as codes and some basic parameters. I personally recommend their use but moderately.

Comment: Consider reading more about separation of concerns and design patterns that aid you with it. Fowler's [UI archs](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) architecture can be a good place to start. Using data-attributes is perfectly OK for passing _presentation only_ information (no business logic) or bindings.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Look at these examples which used the data-attributes ( [get-and-set-data](https://gist.github.com/mbaez/10478264) and [sjs](https://github.com/mbaez/securityjs)

Answer (score 1):

That will work fine, but you should bind your event handler unobtrusively outside your markup so you don't have to hardcode that string:

```
var someValue = "Test 123"; //This could be dynamic
var img = document.queryselector('#imgPerson');
img.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     SetDetailInfo(someValue);
});

function SetDetailInfo(myCustomParam) {
    alert(myCustomParam);
}
```